# Display a view or splash screen before applicationDidEnterBackground (to avoid active view screenshot)

Tags: ios, background, ios7, screenshot, uiapplicationdelegate

I have confidential informations in my app, so I would like to hide them with a splash screen when the app is about to be moved to background.

I do run the app on iOS6 and further.

I tried to display the view in `applicationWillResignActive` but the problem is it display the splash screen even when user swipe control panel for example. I want it to show only when the app is moved to background.

I tried to displayed my splashScreen in `applicationDidEnterBackground` but it takes the screenShot before so informations are displayed at restoration during the animation.

Here the spirit of what I want :

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application {
    [_window addSubview:__splashController.view];
}
```

Comment: AFAIK, you need to do your action inside `applicationWillResignActive` and undo the same action `applicationDidBecomeActive` of `UIApplicationDelegate` methods.

Comment: Problem is, if i do display my splashscreen in `applicationWillResignActive` then it's displayed whenever the user just look at his control panel or double tap on home button...

Comment: `Paypal` iOS app does something similar, they blur their last active view when app enters into background (to secure user info). I would recommend you to study that or some other apps. EDIT: I just noticed that paypal doesn't blur when control panel open up so I believe there is some way so what you are trying to achieve should be feasible. Will keep a watch on this thread.

Comment: It's kinda what I want to do (since my app also deals with bank informations), but i'm not sure paypal let me see its code :/

Comment: I guess that @Ashok solution is probably the best. When a user double tap, receive a call, call the control panel, is resigning the app., most probably it will not care about what your app is showing since it does in a "smooth&cool" way.

Comment: @Andrea - But what he is looking for should be feasible since many other financial (__security-seeking__) apps like `Paypal`, `BofA` does so. (Note - on iPad - control center, notification center etc partially cover the app). I think the solution is not hard but it's just not clicking to me. Let's voted up this question to bring right mind's attention here :). Also @AncAinu - u should give a try of your solution on actual device (not just simulator), if not already done.

Comment: @Ashok's method is what I am looking for. The secure app method whereby switching apps in any way will hide the main view and show a splash screen instead.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

I think the problem is that you are testing in **simulator**. On device, it should work fine.

I tested this and it worked. Add an imageview with your splash image when app enters in background -

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
{

        UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:self.window.bounds];

        imageView.tag = 101;    // Give some decent tagvalue or keep a reference of imageView in self
    //    imageView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
        [imageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Default.png"]];   // assuming Default.png is your splash image's name

        [UIApplication.sharedApplication.keyWindow.subviews.lastObject addSubview:imageView];
}
```

And when app comes back in foreground -

```
- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application
{
    UIImageView *imageView = (UIImageView *)[UIApplication.sharedApplication.keyWindow.subviews.lastObject viewWithTag:101];   // search by the same tag value
    [imageView removeFromSuperview];

}
```

NOTE - On simulator (iOS 7.0), the added subview is not show when you check by pressing home button twice (Cmd + H), but on device it works as expected (like `paypal`, `BofA` apps)

**EDIT: (Additional info)**

In addition to obscuring/replacing sensitive information by adding subview / blur as explained above, **iOS 7** provides you ability to ignore the screen snapshot via `ignoreSnapshotOnNextApplicationLaunch` of `UIApplication` inside `applicationWillResignActive` or `applicationDidEnterBackground`.

*UIApplication.h*

```
// Indicate the application should not use the snapshot on next launch, even if there is a valid state restoration archive.
// This should only be called from methods invoked from State Preservation, else it is ignored.
- (void)ignoreSnapshotOnNextApplicationLaunch NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(7_0);
```

Also, `allowScreenShot` flag can be explored in [Restrictions Payload](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/iPhoneConfigurationProfileRef/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010206-CH1-SW13).

Comment: Yes, it was the day my lightning was dead... Indeed it works fine on true device.

Comment: This works except if a video was playing.  I can hide what video was playing?

Answer (score 10):

**Swift 3.0 Answer** for those who are to lazy to translate.

```
func applicationDidEnterBackground(_ application: UIApplication) {

    let imageView = UIImageView(frame: self.window!.bounds)
    imageView.tag = 101
    imageView.image = ...

    UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.subviews.last?.addSubview(imageView)
 }

func applicationWillEnterForeground(_ application: UIApplication) {

    if let imageView : UIImageView = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.subviews.last?.viewWithTag(101) as? UIImageView {
        imageView.removeFromSuperview()
    }

}
```

Answer (score 4):

Had the same issue, essentially I was using `applicationDidEnterBackground` to show a UIWindow on top of the content, but in iOS8 it didn't work as it did in iOS7.

The solution I found was to create the UIWindow in `applicationWillResignActive` but make it hidden    `securityWindow.hidden = YES`; and then in `applicationDidEnterBackground` all I would do would be to change `securityWindow.hidden = NO`.

This seems to work exactly as iOS7 obscuring the content when multi tasking without affecting the view when using NotificationCenter or ControlPanel.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. Tested on iOS7 through iOS9.

Answer (score 3):

Don't know why, but none of the methods described here worked for me. I was simply trying to cover the screen for security reasons. So, what helped was a Technical Q&A from Apple: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1838/_index.html

I guess the main difference is using a UIViewController? Anyways, the following code works perfectly for me on IOS 9.1:

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
{     
    UIViewController *blankViewController = [UIViewController new];
    blankViewController.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];

    [self.window.rootViewController presentViewController:blankViewController animated:NO completion:NULL];
}

- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application
{
    [self.window.rootViewController dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:NO];
}
```

Comment: If alertview is being displayed, it will not be hidden, how can we hide the alertview on background mode

Comment: Careful using this; if you have a modal presented on your current window and the presentViewController method doesn't complete, when you go back to the foreground your modal may be dismissed instead.

Answer (score 2):

Need to write the code as follows:

```
-(void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
    imageView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:[self.window frame]];
    [imageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Portrait(768x1024).png"]];
    [self.window addSubview:imageView];
}
```

Here to remove the imageview:

```
- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
    if(imageView != nil) {
        [imageView removeFromSuperview];
        imageView = nil;
    }
}
```

It is working and properly tested.

Answer (score 1):

I think this will help for **Swift 3.0**

```
func applicationWillResignActive(_ application: UIApplication) {

        let imageView = UIImageView(frame: self.window!.bounds)
        imageView.tag = 101
        imageView.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
        imageView.contentMode = .center
        imageView.image = #image#
        UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.subviews.last?.addSubview(imageView)

    }

func applicationWillEnterForeground(_ application: UIApplication) {
        ReachabilityManager.shared.stopMonitoring()
        if let imageView : UIImageView = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.subviews.last?.viewWithTag(101) as? UIImageView {
            imageView.removeFromSuperview()
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@interface MyAppDelegate ()
@property (strong, nonatomic) MySplashView *splashView;
@end
@implementation MyAppDelegate
- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application {
    // hide keyboard and show a splash view
    [self.window endEditing:YES];
    MySplashView *splashView = [[MySplashView alloc] initWithFrame:self.window.bounds];
    [self.window addSubview:splashView];
    self.splashView = splashView;
}
- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application {
    // remove the splash view
    if (self.splashView) {
        [self.splashView removeFromSuperview];
        self.splashView = nil;
    }
}
@end
```

Comment: what do you do in case that some system alert is shown on the screen. in this case MySplashView is also shown on the screen. can I avoid this?

Answer (score 0):

This fixed it for me, sorry this is for Xamarin.Forms but you should get the idea. You need to call UIView.SnapshotView(true) in xamarin or `UIView snapshotViewAfterScreenUpdates` on iOS. Works in DidEnterBackground on iOS7, and iOS8:

```
public override void DidEnterBackground(UIApplication uiApplication)
{
    App.Current.MainPage = new DefaultPage();
    **UIApplication.SharedApplication.KeyWindow.SnapshotView(true);**
    base.DidEnterBackground(uiApplication);
}
```