# Hide UI after resigning application

Tags: ios, user-interface, background, passwords

The question is the following:

My app can be protected with a password. When the user presses home button, application resigns inactive. After reopening it, app shows "enter password" screen. But before it shows up, the initial content screen is visible for a moment. Also if, after pressing home button, user enters preview mode (home button double pressed), preview shows content screen, not password screen.

So here are two questions:

1. How can I change UI (to password screen or to some placeholder) before application gets resigned, so that in preview mode user would see something other than the content screen.
2. How can I make application NOT show content screen for a moment (before password screen) when application becomes active again.

Would be thankful for any help.

Comment: What do you do to your UI in your appDelegate `applicationDidEnterBackground:` method?

Comment: At the moment - nothing. Because it dose not change UI in background.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [iOS App Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow.html)

> **What to Do When Moving to the Background**
>
> Apps can use their applicationDidEnterBackground: method to prepare
> for moving to the background state. When moving to the background, all
> apps should do the following:
>
> - **Prepare to have their picture taken.** When the
>   applicationDidEnterBackground: method returns, the system takes a
>   picture of your app’s user interface and uses the resulting image for
>   transition animations. If any views in your interface contain
>   sensitive information, you should hide or modify those views before
>   the applicationDidEnterBackground: method returns.

So, in your `applicationDidEnterBackground` method you should hide your main view and present your 'login' view.

**Update** After a bit more research, it turns out you can't present a view controller - you can only affect the root window.  I have tested the solution in this answer - [Display a view or splash screen before applicationDidEnterBackground (to avoid active view screenshot)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19792850/display-a-view-or-splash-screen-before-applicationdidenterbackground-to-avoid-a) and it works - So you can create an image that shows your login screen and put that over the top of your UI.

Comment: I tried this, but this doesn't seem to work. I tried to show login controller animated and not-animated. Neither worked.

Comment: This is the closest solution right now. Thank you very much!