# How to show custom splash screen on iOS 13 when app enters background?

Tags: swift, background, splash-screen, ios13

The question is similar to this one:

[Display a view or splash screen before applicationDidEnterBackground (to avoid active view screenshot)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19792850/display-a-view-or-splash-screen-before-applicationdidenterbackground-to-avoid-a)

The link above also shows code examples how to implement it.

I need to show for example white screen when the app enters background on "multitasking screen":
[image]

The problem is that way doesn't work on iOS 13! How to fix this issue?

Answer (score 1):

You show that in this `UIWindowSceneDelegate` method. Implement whatever logic you want in it.

```
func sceneDidEnterBackground(_ scene: UIScene)
```

Comment: Maybe. But the project is developed starting with the older Xcode version which didn't know about `UIWindowSceneDelegate` and `SwiftUI`. Should the project be `SwiftUI`-based to use it?

Comment: it does not have to SwiftUI based

Comment: ok, how to add `UIWindowSceneDelegate ` to the existing project?

Comment: you don't have to use UIWindowSceneDelegate for iOS 13 anyways. does your app delegate conform to the `UIApplicationDelegate`

Comment: I subscribed to `UIApplicationDidEnterBackground` in my custom class. The code is executed as in the previous iOS versions but nothing happens in UI.

Comment: is the UI just dark or you're sure nothing happens

Comment: try adding `<key>UIUserInterfaceStyle</key>
 <string>Light</string>` to your plist lets see what happens

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200593/discussion-between-vyachaslav-gerchicov-and-nscoder).

Answer (score 1):

I use this (my own) implementation for functionality you ask for both iOS 12 & iOS 13 support

**AppDelegate**:

```
private var blankWindow: BlankWindow?

// MARK: Shared AppDelegate

extension AppDelegate {
    static func blankWindowShouldAppear(blankWindow: inout BlankWindow?) {
        blankWindow = BlankWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
        blankWindow?.makeKeyAndVisible()
    }

    static func blankWindowShouldDisappear(window: UIWindow?, blankWindow: inout BlankWindow?) {
        window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
        blankWindow = nil
    }

    @available(iOS 13.0, *)
    static func blankWindowShouldAppear(_ windowScene: UIWindowScene, blankWindow: inout BlankWindow?) {
        blankWindow = BlankWindow(windowScene: windowScene)
        blankWindow?.makeKeyAndVisible()
    }
}

// MARK: Old life cycle methods

extension AppDelegate {
    /// ⚠️ Methods here will not be called under iOS 13 due to new SceneDelegate life cycle

    func applicationWillEnterBackground(_ application: UIApplication) {
        AppDelegate.blankWindowShouldAppear(blankWindow: &blankWindow)
    }

    func applicationWillEnterForeground(_ application: UIApplication) {
        AppDelegate.blankWindowShouldDisappear(window: window, blankWindow: &blankWindow)
    }
}
```

**SceneDelegate**:

```
private var blankWindow: BlankWindow?

// MARK: New life cycle methods

@available(iOS 13.0, *)
extension SceneDelegate {
    /// ⚠️ As for now, we use fallback to AppDelegate shared methods to reduce code duplication
    /// Not all of the new life cycle methods are implemented here, yet

    func sceneWillEnterForeground(_ scene: UIScene) {
        AppDelegate.blankWindowShouldDisappear(window: window, blankWindow: &blankWindow)
    }

    func sceneWillEnterBackground(_ scene: UIScene) {
        guard let windowScene = (scene as? UIWindowScene) else { return }
        AppDelegate.blankWindowShouldAppear(windowScene, blankWindow: &blankWindow)
    }
}
```

Where **BlankWindow** class is a UIWindow you wanna show to a user at this moment

Comment: would be nice if you could give the BlankWIndow implementation

Comment: @Async- the BlankWindow may be any subclass of UIWindow, you may customize it however you want. There is now special or universal implementation for that :)